# Excel nested IFs stringing together FALSE values and rendering #VALUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following nested IFs (I know the comments aren't Excel comments, but using them in my text editor helps me through the logic)

```
// start by seeing if there is an order date
=IF(    
    $C46<>"",
    //there is an order date. have the parts begun to arrive @ P2?
    IF( 
        $D46<>"",
        //parts have begun to arrive @ P2. Have they finished transferring to Brevard?
        IF(
            $F46<>"",
            // product has finished transferring to warehouse. has it begun to ship?
            IF(
                $G46<>"",
                // product has begun to ship. Has it shipped completely?
                IF(
                    $H46<>"",
                    // has shipped completely. this ends the cycle
                    IF( 
                        AND(J$5>=$G46,J$5<=$H46),
                        "S",
                        "error - shipped completely"
                    ),
                    // has NOT shipped completely. Here's where to TODAY() formula comes in
                    IF(
                        AND(J$5>=$G46,J$5<=TODAY()),
                        "S",
                        "error - began shipping, but not complete"
                    )
                )
                // product has NOT begun to ship; HAS completely transferred to Brevard. It's in inventory until shipping begins
                IF(
                    AND(J$5>$F46,J$5<=TODAY()),
                    "I",
                    "error - finished transferring to Brevard. in Inventory. Not begun to ship"
                )
            ),
            // product has begun assembly, but has not finished transferring to Brevard.
            IF(
                AND(J$5<=$D46,J$5<=TODAY()),
                "A",
                "error - assembly has begun, has not finished transferring"
            )
        ),
        //there is an order date, but parts have not arrived at P2
        IF(
            AND(J$5<=C46,J$5<=TODAY()),
            "O",
            "error - order has been taken, assembly has not begun"
        )
    ),
    // there is no order date
    ""
)
```

When rendering all this, Excel is stringing together the FALSE values and as a result, they are turned into #VALUE, which ruins the entire formula.

What am I doing wrong? If I remove the FALSE values, it still renders #VALUE. I don't understand how to tell it to do exactly nothing, especially multiple times in one algorithm.

Comment: Have you tried Evaluate formula in Excel? It can be found in the Formulas tab, and it allow you to evaluate your formula step by step so you can see where it grabs the #VALUE error.

Comment: Does this work - `=IF(AND(C46<>"",D46<>"",F46<>"",G46<>"",H46<>""),IF(OR(AND(J$5>=$G46,J$5<=$H46),AND(J$5>=$G46,J$5<=TODAY())),"S",IF(AND(J$5>$F46,J$5<=TODAY()),"A",IF(AND(J$5<=C46,J$5<=TODAY()),"O",""))),"")` - I think I got your logic.

Comment: @Grosi yes I have done that. That's how I know that Excel is stringing together the FALSE values for the IF statements to come to the #VALUE error. None of the IF statements themselves result in a #VALUE error.

Comment: @BigBen That does not work. Each IF statement must be evaluated individually for the whole thing to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are having too many `ELSE` in the formula. Thus, after some debugging this is what you get:

[image]

at some point. Thus, the `#VALUE` appears. In general, the nested if syntax in Excel is like this:

[image]

Thus, every new `=IF` is in the `ELSE` place. Thus, only one `ELSE` is written (number 5 from the screenshot above)

[IF function – nested formulas and avoiding pitfalls](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-%E2%80%93-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8)

---

<kbd>F9</kbd> is a good friend in the evaluation of a big formula. Once you select the formula, select a whole internal formula and press <kbd>F9</kbd> to see the result.

Comment: Ok so it looks like I need to change the IF->AND formulas into something else so there's no IF-ELSE there. I'll have to think through that because I'm not sure how to get the results I'm trying to get in the IF->AND from any other method.